# How to execute some code with AOP before each method of a Spring controller and have the Method object

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aop

Given a method in a Spring controller, I'd like to execute a "before" handler. I tried some AspectJ code to do that but I can't work it out. What I'd like is to obtain the target Method object so that I could process its Annotations. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

Write a class which implements 'MethodBeforeAdvice' interface and overwrite before() Method in that class, in which you can implement the logic what you want.

And also specify your custom class  as the property of `org.springframework.aop.support.RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor` in Spring XML file.

```
 ex: 
    <bean id="methodAuthzAdvice" class="com.src.customClassMethodBeforeAdvice"/>
    <bean id="methodAuthzAdvisor" class="org.springframework.aop.support.RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor">
         <ref local="methodAuthzAdvice"/>
            <property name="advice">
                <ref local="methodAuthzAdvice"/>
            </property>     
                     <property name="pattern">
                <value>.*</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

use `methodAuthzAdvice` id as an interceptor property to your handler class in xml file.

Comment: I am using annotated controllers (so they are not in my xml). How do I set up interceptors for every controller (without listing them all?)

Comment: You can specify annotations for Interceptors in the class level.                                                               [ex: @Interceptors({methodAuthzAdvice.class})                 public class foo{ public void dosomething() { ... } }]